# Passing values to a sparse matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

Might sound too simple to you but I need some help in regrad to do all folowings in one shot instead of defining redundant variables i.e. *tmp_x*, *tmp_y*:

```
X= sparse(numel(find(G==0)),2);
[tmp_x, temp_y] = ind2sub(size(G), find(G == 0));
X(:)=[tmp_x, tmp_y];
```

(More info: *G* is a sparse matrix)

I tried:

```
X(:)=ind2sub(size(G), find(G == 0));
```

but that threw an error.
How can I achieve this without defining *tmp_x*, *tmp_y*?

Comment: You should specify the ERROR. "That threw an error" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @SanthanSalai - As you've become more active, this will probably not be the last time people expect us to be clairvoyant and expect us to know the errors.  The best thing to do is exactly what you've done.  Be blunt and tell them that we aren't mind readers.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in one shot?  What's wrong with how you have it currently?  Donald Knuth, one of the most prominent computer scientists in the 20th century, said "*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*".  Is there a reason why you want this to be done?

Comment: @SanthanSalai: The error is somehow irrelevant to my question. I can't recall as I am not with my computer right now. Out of memory it was a mismatch in argument sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments with your code:

1. `numel(find(G == 0))` is probably one of the worst ways to determine how many entries that are zero in your matrix.  I would personally do `numel(G) - nnz(G)`.  `numel(G)` determines how many elements are in `G` and `nnz(G)` determines how many **non-zero** values are in `G`.  Subtracting these both would give you the total number of elements that are zero.
2. What you are doing is first declaring `X` to be sparse... then when you're doing the final assignment in the last line to `X`, it reconverts the matrix to `double`.  As such, the first statement is totally redundant.

---

If I understand what you are doing, you want to find the row and column locations of what is zero in `G` and place these into a `N x 2` matrix.  Currently with what MATLAB has available, this cannot be done without intermediate variables.  The functions that you'd typically use (`find`, `ind2sub`, etc.) require intermediate variables if you want to capture the row and column locations.  Using one output variable will give you the column locations only.

You don't have a choice but to use intermediate variables.  However, if you want to make this more efficient, you don't even need to use `ind2sub`.  Just use `find` directly:

```
[I,J] = find(~G);
X = [I,J];
```